# Python tkinter state change creating new window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, state

When trying to change the state of TEntry1 which is controlled by the button in the upper right instead of changing the state of TEntry1 it creates a new window that has TEntry1 greyed out and all variable inputs blank.

The GUI was generated by PAGE

PAGE exports to 2 files, I've combined the 2 for this question

The window to the left is the program running as desired, the button will initially say start, then clicking on it will will switch to running mode and changes the text to stop.  It is also supposed to grey out the entry widget, but instead creates a new window with the entry widget greyed out

I believe the issue is happening in disableentry(): with how the attribute is called

```
def disableentry():
    print("disableentry() start")
    root = tk.Tk()
    Toplevel1(root).TEntry1.configure(state='disabled')
```

[image: Example]

```
import sys
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def destroy_Toplevel1():
    thread0.stop()

class Toplevel1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.style.map('.',background=
            [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])

        top.geometry("460x406+660+210")
        top.minsize(120, 1)
        top.maxsize(3844, 1061)
        top.resizable(0,  0)
        top.title("PAGE GUI")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.TEntry1 = ttk.Entry(top)
        self.TEntry1.place(x=76, y=41, height=21, width=137)
        self.TEntry1.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TEntry1.configure(cursor="ibeam")
        self.TEntry1.configure(textvariable=entry1text)

        self.Label1 = tk.Label(top)
        self.Label1.place(x=21, y=41, height=31, width=38)
        self.Label1.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label1.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''IP 1''')

        self.Button1 = tk.Button(top)
        self.Button1.place(x=330, y=41, height=24, width=107)
        self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button1.configure(textvariable=button_text)
        self.Button1.configure(command=guicontrols.start_stop)

class guisetup():
    def set_Tk_var():
        global running_status
        running_status = tk.IntVar()
        running_status.set(0)
        global button_text 
        button_text = tk.StringVar()
        button_text.set('Start')
        global entry1text
        entry1text = tk.StringVar()
        entry1text.set('')

    def vp_start_gui():
        global val, w, root
        root = tk.Tk()
        guisetup.set_Tk_var()
        top = Toplevel1 (root)
        root.mainloop()

class guithread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self

    def run(self):
        guisetup.vp_start_gui()

class guicontrols():
    def disableentry():
        print("disableentry() start")
        root = tk.Tk()
        Toplevel1(root).TEntry1.configure(state='disabled')

    def start_stop():
        print('PLA_support.start_stop')
        if (running_status.get() == 1):
            button_text.set("Stop")
            running_status.set(0)
            guicontrols.disableentry()
        else:
            button_text.set("Start")
            running_status.set(1)
        sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread0 = guithread()
    thread0.start()
```

Comment: what is your issue exactly? also please provide a [mre]

Comment: Your code is incomplete and not correctly formatted. Please use correct, 4-space indentation, and include all of the code so that we can better help answering your question. Also, you have variables with `self.` in front, but there is no class in the given code.

Comment: What is wrong with the code? For example, is it that it creates a new window, or is it that the entry is disabled, or that all the other entries are enabed as well? Or something else?

Comment: Your `vp_start_gui` function explicitly creates a new window. Do you not want it to create a new window?

Comment: Instead of changing TEntry1 to disabled it creates a new window with TEntry1 disabled, my gut instinct is that it's called wrong here: Toplevel1(root).TEntry1.configure(state='disabled')

Comment: Maybe consider putting all the code that's not already a class into one class. There are too many dependencies in the functions to be able to rearrange them so that the code works.

Comment: @SamMatzko I edited the code putting more things into classes as you'd suggested

Comment: @Straconis: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant to try to solve the problem, not necessarily to make the question's code different. If you are unsure about how to write classes, there are plenty of related questions on SO.

Comment: @SamMatzko most of the output and formatting came from PAGE, I've just been trying to get the pieces working

Comment: @Straconis: Do you need to keep all the `threading` stuff in there? Unless you have a reason for it being there, there's no need to use it (I'm working on an answer :-)).

Comment: Also, do you want to reanable `TEntry1` when the user clicks the button again?

Comment: @SamMatzko the threading is there for a reason, and yes, TEntry 1 would be re-enabled after the stop.  Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cleaned-up version of your code. I put everything to do with the window into one class: `App`, so that all the variables can be accessed properly.

```
import sys
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    """The main window."""

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        # Set the theme
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

        self.style = ttk.Style()

        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.', background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.', foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.', font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.style.map(
            '.',
            background=[('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)]
        )

        self.geometry("460x406+660+210")
        self.minsize(120, 1)
        self.maxsize(3844, 1061)
        self.resizable(0,  0)
        self.title("PAGE GUI")
        self.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        # Running status
        self.running_status = tk.IntVar()
        self.running_status.set(1)

        # Create the widgets
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create the widgets and add them to the window."""

        self.entry1text = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry1text.set("")
        self.TEntry1 = ttk.Entry(
            self,
            takefocus="",
            cursor="xterm",
            textvariable=self.entry1text
        )
        self.TEntry1.place(x=76, y=41, height=21, width=137)

        # The label-
        self.Label1 = tk.Label(
            self,
            activebackground="#f9f9f9",
            activeforeground="black",
            background="#d9d9d9",
            disabledforeground="#a3a3a3",
            foreground="#000000",
            highlightbackground="#d9d9d9",
            highlightcolor="black",
            text="IP 1"
        )
        self.Label1.place(x=21, y=41, height=31, width=38)

        # The button
        self.button_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.button_text.set('Start')
        self.Button1 = tk.Button(
            self,
            activebackground="#ececec",
            activeforeground="#000000",
            background="#d9d9d9",
            disabledforeground="#a3a3a3",
            foreground="#000000",
            highlightbackground="#d9d9d9",
            highlightcolor="black",
            pady="0",
            textvariable=self.button_text,
            command=self.start_stop
        )
        self.Button1.place(x=330, y=41, height=24, width=107)

    def disable_entry(self):
        self.TEntry1.config(state="disabled")

    def enable_entry(self):
        self.TEntry1.config(state="enabled")

    def start_stop(self):
        print('PLA_support.start_stop')
        if (self.running_status.get() == 1):
            self.button_text.set("Stop")
            self.running_status.set(0)
            self.disable_entry()
        else:
            self.button_text.set("Start")
            self.running_status.set(1)
            self.enable_entry()



class guithread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.app = App()

    def run(self):
        self.app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread0 = guithread()
    thread0.run()
```

I also put the widget arguments that were originally in tons of `config()` functions as arguments for the widget classes themselves; it's better syntax.

I kept the threading and added a function that re-enables the entry when the user clicks the button. I also changed the line `self.running_status.set(0)` after `self.running_status = tkinter.IntVar()` to `self.running_status.set(1)`. This fixes an error where, when the program first starts, you have to click the button twice before anything happens.

Comment: do you have a way to contact you to look at the full code?  It appears that the button press may be waiting for the second thread to finish to change to the stop button, and you can't stop it without the stop button

Comment: @Straconis: That's not good! This is definitely something you could post a question about, and if the full code is too long, you could just set up an example second thread to demonstrate. Be sure to look on SO first and make sure that there are no similar questions that might have the answer.